# Can i Use Telerik UI and Kendo UI in Same Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to use kendo UI in nopcommerce, but nopcommerce use Telerik UI ,so can i use both in same project?

Is there any conflict issue or any other issue are created?

Regards,

Comment: What package of Telerik UI are you pertaining to? Telerik also has Kendo UI package

Comment: Telerik 2013.2.611.340  Can i use kendo UI With this? and i want to use this in nopcommerce 3.2 can i ?

Comment: This really seems like a question for the Telerik forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI is essentially a complete re-write of the Telerik extensions in NOP Commerce.  All of the DLLs, JS and CSS themes are separate.  That being said, they *should* be able to work together, the only issue you'll likely have is with jQuery versions.  I don't remember what the exact versions are, but Telerik has a max supported version and Kendo UI (latest) has a min of I think 1.10.x?

Comment: Where can i check this versions of jquery ?